# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'qa')

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-google-charts, webdatarocks

I can't fix this. I'm using webdatarocks with googlecharts in Next.js. When I change the pivot design to flat mode appears an error when this code are executed in my component:

```
window.webdatarocks.googlecharts.getData(
        { type: props?.chartType },
        drawChart,
        drawChart
      );
```

This is the drawChart function:

```
  const drawChart = (_data) => {
    console.log("DRAW CHART", _data);
    setData(_data?.data?.length ? _data.data : []);
    setDataReady(true);
    setTitle(_data?.options?.title);
  };
```

This is my chart component (import { Chart } from "react-google-charts";) returned:

```
<Chart
  id={props.chartContainerId}
  loader={<CircularProgress />}
  chartType={ChartTypes[props?.chartType]}
  options={{ title: title, height: props?.height || 500 }}
  data={data}
  width="100%"
/>
```

My package.json dependencies:

```
"react-google-charts": "^4.0.0",
"react-webdatarocks": "^1.4.4",
"webdatarocks": "1.4.2",
```

And this is the error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'qa')
> at d.zx (webdatarocks.js?9fcc:176:131)
> at d.getData (webdatarocks.js?9fcc:174:164)
> at h.getData (webdatarocks.js?9fcc:156:356)
> at k.getData (webdatarocks.js?9fcc:1082:273)
> at Object.PivotApi.k.getData (webdatarocks.js?9fcc:1089:292)
> at Object.WebDataRocksGooglecharts.getData (webdatarocks.googlecharts.js?0db4:31:1)
> at getData (GoogleChartReact.js?8bed:23:26)
> at eval (GoogleChartReact.js?8bed:7:6)
> at invokePassiveEffectCreate (react-dom.development.js?ac89:23487:1)
> at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js?ac89:3945:1)
> at HTMLUnknownElement.dispatchEvent ()
> at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js?ac89:3994:1)
> at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js?ac89:4056:1)
> at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js?ac89:23574:1)
> at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js?c964:468:1)
> at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js?ac89:11276:1)
> at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js?ac89:23447:1)
> at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js?ac89:22269:1)
> at eval (react-dom.development.js?ac89:11327:1)
> at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js?c964:468:1)
> at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js?ac89:11276:1)
> at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js?ac89:11322:1)
> at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js?ac89:11309:1)
> at discreteUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js?ac89:22420:1)
> at discreteUpdates (react-dom.development.js?ac89:3756:1)
> at dispatchDiscreteEvent (react-dom.development.js?ac89:5889:1)

Comment: maybe the issue is because you are accessing `window`. and when nextjs execute code server-side window would be `undefined`. Are you executing the window code inside if conditon? Have you tried dynamically loading the chart component in client-side?

Comment: the method exist in window and the chart works fine. The problem appears when the pivot design is in flat form. And the error happen inside window.webdatarocks.googlecharts.getData function

Comment: I think that flat mode was not developed for chart generation

Answer (score 1):

The getData API call is supported only in a compact/classic form in order to return pre-aggregated data for charts.